# Session table not being populated in db2

Tags: sql, db2

I'm using a stored procedure with some session tables. Everything worked fine until I've tested my stored procedure with new data.

The cursor used to retrieve data outside the session table returns the records as expected however when the same cursor is used with a session table nothing is being written in the session table.

```
    INSERT INTO SESSION.TEMP_UNTIL (CUSTOMID, UNTIL) 
            WITH PERIODS AS (
                SELECT NAT.UNTIL FROM TOPM.NATIONALITYHIST NAT WHERE NAT.CUSTOMID = custId
                UNION
                SELECT CIVIL.UNTIL FROM TOPM.MARITALSTATUSHIST CIVIL WHERE CIVIL.CUSTOMID = custId
                UNION
                SELECT COUNTRY.UNTIL FROM TOPM.COUNTRYOFRESIDENCEHIST COUNTRY WHERE COUNTRY.CUSTOMID = custId
            )
            SELECT custId, PERIODS.UNTIL FROM PERIODS ORDER BY PERIODS.UNTIL ASC;
```

What could be the reason for such a behavior, how can the above behavior be avoided?

The temporary table is declared as follows:

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_UNTIL (
    CUSTOMID VARCHAR(36), UNTIL DATE
)
```

Comment: What’s the exact `DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE` statement you use?

Comment: I have added the declaration for the temp table

Comment: @SocketM debug your code. You don't show enough code to allow an answer. Most likely you have untested assumptions. Your procedure should contain exception handlers that either abort on error or handle the error appropriately.  You can also improve the traceability of the stored procedure by using `get diagnostics v_numrows = row_count;` where `v_numrows` is declared as a bigint, then use dbms_output.put_line to show actual row counts for each  insert/update/delete.  You have all the information to debug the problem yourself, so use the right tools...

Comment: After debugging I have discovered the issue with not inserting into a table even if when you run it outside the stored procedure the insert is being done.

Answer (score 1):

The default for `DECLARE GLOBAL TEMOPORARY TABLE` is `DELETE ON COMMIT`, so the rows only exist in the temporary table for the life of your transaction.

You either need to perform all work within the scope of a single transaction, or add an `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS` clause to your `DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE` statement.  For example:

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_UNTIL (
    CUSTOMID VARCHAR(36), UNTIL DATE
)
    ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
    NOT LOGGED;
```

Comment: I'm performung all the work in a transaction. Do you know a way to find if the statement executed is causing issues, for exemple the date field format.

Answer (score 0):

What's the result of the following `select count(1) ...` statements as is and with uncommented `on commit preserve rows` line, when you run the script with autocommit switched off in your client tool?

```
declare global temporary table session.tables as 
(
select * from syscat.tables
) 
definition only
with replace 
--on commit preserve rows
not logged;

insert into session.tables
select * from syscat.tables;

select count(1) from session.tables;

commit;

select count(1) from session.tables;
```

Comment: 1651, it seems that it's working. I have replaced into the stored procedure the temporary table with a standard table and the result is the same (no data is being retrieved from the cursor into the standard table) . If you run separately, outside stored procedure, just the cursor records are being retrieved. More over I have checked if the variable custId has value before executing the INSERT INTO and it has value. Additionally I have run the INSERT INTO from the stored procedure with embedded value (hard coded) for custId and the result is the same(no data is being retrived). An advice please

Comment: The advise is to provide some reproducible example showing the problem. If your real example is quite a complex and long, then try to provide it in some shorter (and may be schematic) form. Like the my one above.